# SPFx - This site can’t be reached after running gulp serve

Tags: sharepoint-framework, gulp

Any one with the solution to the follow error ?

Zero edit since `yo @microsoft/sharepoint` then `gulp serve`

The following page error opens :

[image]

Runing on node 6.12 . with the following installed :

`├── @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.4.0
├── generator-sharepoint-app@0.0.72
├── gulp@3.9.1
├── npm@3.10.10
└── yo@2.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

Try :

> gulp trust-dev-cert

Then

> gulp serve